# Rewriting function haskell

Tags: haskell

```
mostCommonNeighbour pairsTally word =
  let matchedPairTally = neighboursTally word pairsTally
  in if matchedPairTally == [] then Nothing -- Has no neighbour
     else let commonNeighbour = (fst $ largestTally matchedPairTally)
          in if (fst commonNeighbour) == word then Just (snd commonNeighbour)
             else Just (fst commonNeighbour)
  where
    -- Filter out all Pairs from pairsTally that does not contain word
    neighboursTally :: String -> PairsTally -> PairsTally
    neighboursTally word pairsTally = filter ((inPair word).fst) pairsTally

    -- Check if a word is contained in a pair
    inPair :: String -> (String, String) -> Bool
    inPair word pair
      | word == (fst pair) || word == (snd pair) = True
      | otherwise                                = False

    -- Return the largest Tally in a PairsTally
    largestTally :: PairsTally -> ((String, String), Int)
    largestTally pairsTally = foldr bigTally (("", ""), 0) pairsTally
      where
        bigTally :: ((String, String), Int) -> ((String, String), Int) -> ((String, String), Int)
        bigTally tally1 tally2
          | snd tally1 > snd tally2 = tally1
          | otherwise               = tally2
```

Anyone know a good way to rewrite this function?, feel like it's a little long and am just checking if anyone knows how to make it shorter

Comment: If it currently works, http://codereview.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for this kind of question (open-ended requests for improvements to working code).

Comment: Use more pattern matching, and check out `Data.List.maximumBy`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this looks pretty decent:

```
import Data.Ord
import Safe

mostCommonNeighbour pairsTally word = fst <$> maximumByMay (comparing snd)
    [ (here, n)
    | ((w1, w2), n) <- pairsTally
    , (here, there) <- [(w1, w2), (w2, w1)]
    , there == word
    ]
```

The `Safe` module may be obtained from the [safe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe) package; or you can copy `maximumByMay` into your codebase yourself (it is just two lines long).